# Верстка цены над кнопкой

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, flexbox, grid

Есть страницы - https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?f=discount.any%2Crating.any&sorting=price_asc, https://www.mvideo.ru/komputernaya-tehnika-4107/monobloki-181/f/category=monobloki-603?reff=menu_main. Требуется, чтобы в карточке товара цена товара со значком рубля (покажите также, как отобразить значок рубля) отображалась чуть выше (пикселей на 10-15), чем кнопка В корзину(как на 2-х вышеприведенных страницах). Я плохо представляю этот код (выше на 10-15px) в полном объеме. Приведите пожалуйста пример реального кода, отображающего цену с вышеуказанным условием (выше на 10-15px). (Я новичок - прошу отнестись с пониманием). Я не понимаю как можно встроить в код

```
productcard+='<div class="dynamic ProductBuyPart">'+ '<button type="submit" class="ProductAddToBasket" value="В корзину">Купить</button>' +'</div>';
```

кнопку на 10-15 px выше чем приведенная кнопка (класс `ProductAddToBasket`).

```js
        // такой же код, что и код выше - только для черных пунктов меню типа Моноблоки 
        let categoryflag='';
            $('.submenu__title a').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log('Inner check');             
                categoryflag=event.target.innerHTML;
                subcategoryflag=categoryflag;
                console.log(categoryflag);
                $.ajax ({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '../php/ajaxsubcategory1.php',
                    cache: false,                   
                    data: {categoryflag: categoryflag, subcategoryflag: subcategoryflag},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    complete: function(data) {
                        console.log(data.header);
                        console.log(data.countrecords);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('check');
                        console.log(data);
                        $('.rightmenu').html(data.result.msg);
                        let centeroutput='<div id=\"topcenterarea\">'+'<h1>'+data.result.header+' '+data.result.countrecords+' товара' + data.output[0]['screendiagonal'] + '</h1>'+'</div>';
                        
                        
                        productcardsoutput='';
                        // productcard='<div class="ProductCardBlock">';
                        
                        
                        for (let i=0; i<data.result.countrecords; i++)
                            {
                                productcard='<div class="ProductCardBlock">';
                                productcard+='<div class="dynamic ProductImage">';
                                productcard+='<div id="ImageWrapper">';
                                productcard+='<img class="ProductPicture" src='+'"../images/'+data.output[i]['imagepath']+'">';
                                productcard+='</div>';
                                productcard+='</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="dynamic ProductDescription">';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductName">' + data.output[i]['monoblockname'] +', ' + data.output[i]['color']+'</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductScreenParamsWrapper">' + '<span class="text">' + 'Диагональ/разрешение ' + '</span>' + '<span class="spaces">' + ''  + '</span>' + '<span class="ProductScreenParams">' + ' '+ data.output[i]['screendiagonal'] + '/' + data.output[i]['resolution'] + 'пикс.' +'</span>'+'</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductCpuTypeWrapper">' + '<span class="text">' + 'Тип процессора ' + '</span>' + '<span class="spaces">' + ''  + '</span>' + '<span class="ProductCpuType">'+ ' ' + data.output[i]['cputype'] +'</span>' +'</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductCpuFrequencyWrapper">'+ '<span class="text">'+ 'Частота процессора ' +'</span>'+'<span class="spaces">' + ''  + '</span>'+ '<span class="ProductCpuFrequency">' + ' ' +data.output[i]['frequency'] +'</span>'+'</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductRAMWrapper">' + '<span class="text">' + 'Оперативная память (RAM) ' + '</span>' + '<span class="spaces">' + ''  + '</span>' + '<span class="ProductRAM">' + ' '+ data.output[i]['ramsize']  +'</span>'+'</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="ProductVideoCardWrapper">' + '<span class="text">'+'Графический контроллер '+'</span>' + '<span class="spaces">' + ''  + '</span>' + '<span class="ProductVideoCard">' + ' ' + data.output[i]['videocard']  +'</span>'+'</div>';
                                
                                if (data.output[i]['memorytype']=='SSD') {
                                    productcard+='<div class="ProductDisksAndDrivesWrapper">' + '<span class="text">' + 'Объем SSD ' + '</span>' + '<span class="spaces">' + ''  + '</span>' +'<span class="ProductDisksAndDrives">' + ' ' +
                                    data.output[i]['sizememorydata']  +'</span>'+'</div>';
                                }
                                else if (data.output[i]['memorytype']=='HDD') {
                                    productcard+='<div class="ProductDisksAndDrivesWrapper">' + '<span class="text">' + 'Объем HDD ' + '</span>' + '<span class="spaces">' + ''  + '</span>' + '<span class="ProductDisksAndDrives">' + ' ' +  data.output[i]['sizememorydata']  +'</span>'+'</div>';
                                };
                                
                                productcard+='</div>';
                                productcard+='<div class="dynamic ProductBuyPart">'+ '<button type="submit" class="ProductAddToBasket" value="В корзину">Купить</button>' +'</div>';
                                // productcard+='<div class="ProductScreenParams">'+ 'Диагональ/разрешение ' + data.output[i]['screendiagonal'] + '/' + data.output[i]['resolution'] + 'пикс.' +'</div>';
                                
                                
                                // productcard+='</div>';
                                // productcard+='</div>';
                                // productcard+='</div>';
                                // productcard+='</div>';
                                productcard+='</div>';
                                productcardsoutput+=productcard;
                            }
                        
                        centeroutput+=productcardsoutput;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как задать расстояние типа 50% - 15px?

Comment: Так вопрос то в чем? Что вы пытались сделать? Что не получилось?

Comment: @Greg-- Я не представляю как задать расположение кнопки, находящейся на 10-15px выше чем кнопка в В корзину.

Comment: У вас указано что требуется в карточке товара это выполнить, а в карточке товара цена и кнопка стоят друг под другом [Карточка товара](https://www.citilink.ru/product/monoblok-irbis-mb2380-23-8-intel-core-i5-n3350-4gb-500gb-intel-windows-1443677/)

Comment: Или нужно расстояние между ценой и кнопкой сделать 15 px?

Comment: @Greg да между ценой и кнопкой расстояние нужно сделать 10-15px.

Comment: Если вы не знаете как задать расположение кнопки, какие селекторы вы знаете? Как кнопку и цену найти в DOM?

Comment: @Greg-- Напишите. Я новичок.

Comment: На данный момент между кнопкой и ценой расстояние 20px, нужно увеличить на 10-15 (получится 30-35) или уменьшить на 5 чтоб получилось 10-15?

Comment: @Greg-- уменьшить на 5, чтобы получилось 10-15.

Comment: Ниписать что? Это не база фриланса, если хотите чтоб за вас код написали создайте заявку на любом фриланс сайте. Если же хотите найти решение то [начать от сюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps)

Comment: @Greg-- и карточка товара это то, что приведено на https://www.mvideo.ru/komputernaya-tehnika-4107/monobloki-181/f/category=monobloki-603?reff=menu_main, а именно одна из списка отображаемых пунктов-товаров.

Comment: Может кто то и напишет, может кому и занятся нечем, это площадка для тех кто застрял в каком то вопросе, а вы даже не пытались разобратся, вы не уважаете время и работу других людей. Если бы вы написали что Пожалуйста у меня не получается то то то - было бы нормально, а вы написали `Напишите. Я новичек` новичек в чем? Кто вам обязан чем и что писать?

Comment: @Greg-- я имел ввиду `Напишите, пожалуйста`. А вопросе я привел код, как внедрить в который цену товара. я не понимаю - как в полном объеме (наверно в %) задать размер и положение кнопки.

Comment: Вы привели js код, а за расположение блоков отвечает css

Comment: @Greg-- productcard+='<div class="dynamic ProductBuyPart">'+ '<button type="submit" class="ProductAddToBasket" value="В корзину">Купить</button>' +'</div>';

Answer (score 0):

> покажите также, как отобразить значок рубля

Знак рубля можно отобразить вставив этот код `&#8381`. Пример: `<p>1000&#8381;</p>`

Comment: И так ₽
На выбор :)